# Turning a class into a super class of an other class

Tags: python

Let's say I have an abstract `A` as defined below

```py
import abc


class A(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        pass

    def foo(self) -> int:
        return len(self) - 1
```

I would like to define a class `B` that is the same as `str` but that also implements `foo` using `__len__` from `str`. On way I can think of is like this to define `B` as inheriting from `str` and `A`.

```py
class B(str, A):
    pass
```

The issue with this solution is that if you add two instance of `B` or if you slice a instance of `B` you get back a string when I would like an instance of `B`. Is there a good way to achieve what I want without redefining every method I want to use on B?